# How do I filter a specific folder inside a jar while the jar is located in a zip file?

Tags: java, maven, proguard, proguard-maven-plugin

I am using Proguard to shrink my deployment package which is a zip file containing multiple jar files.

```
-injars deployment_package.zip
```

the `deployment_package.zip` structure looks like this:

```
deployment_package.zip
- main/classes/...
- lib
  - libraryA.jar
  - libraryB.jar
    -META-INF
```

I wanted Proguard to filter out the META-INF folder inside libraryB.jar (so that it is not included on the outjar). How do I achieve this using proguard?

I have tried

```
-injars deployment_package.zip (!lib/libraryB.jar/META-INF)
```

but it does not seem to work (META-INF folder still exists in outjar).

Comment: quick question,  the libaryA.jar, librayB.jar etc belongs to you or external jars ?

Comment: @Shailesh they are external jars. I placed all of the dependencies jars on the `lib` folder inside the deployment_package.zip

Comment: ok, I will give a try to your problem, one more question , how are you using proguard , I mean its gui or maven plugin etc

Comment: thanks for taking the time! I am using proguard with maven plugin from https://github.com/wvengen/proguard-maven-plugin

Comment: if you can place a dummy project on github that would expedite